# Substitution instance of a well-formed formula ( if two variables are replaced)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, substitution

According to my Discrete Mathematics books:

A statement formula p is called a Substitution instance of another
statement formula q, if p can be generated from q by substituting
formulas for some variables of q. Here, the condition required is that
the same formula is substituted for the same variable each time it
occurs.

As it says that
substituting formulas for some variables of q

so I was thinking that **If I substitute two different statement formulas for two different variables of q to get p then will p still be called as the Substitution instance of q?**

For example,
let's say **((p.q)+r)** is a WFF so if I replace q with (q+p) and r with (q+r) to get **(p.(q+p))+(q+r)**, then will the latter be a Substitution Instance of the initial one?

Comment: Yes, as long as you replace all occurrences of the same variable by the same formula, you get a substitution instance. In particular, your example at the end of the question is a substitution instance (assuming $(p.q+r)$ means $((p.q)+r)$, not $(p.(q+r))$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The idea lies in that a substitution instance has the same truth value as the original formula if the original formula is a tautology.  That substitution preserves the truth of the original formula, or at least does not lead from a true formula to a false one.  If you allow for the same variable to get substituted with two different formulas, then as William Eliot suggest, a substitution instance of a tautology will no longer be true for all valuations of it's variables as a tautology is.

For instance, consider the tautology (in Polish notation) Cpp.  If we substitute the first p with 'Cpp' and the second with 'NCpp', then we obtain CCppNCpp.  But, Cpp is always true, and NCpp is always false.  Thus, we would have a substitution instance of a tautology which would always be false, when all substitution instances of a tautology come as intended to hold true.

Thus, we have the uniformity requirement for substitution instances of formulas.

"For example, let's say (p.q+r) is a WFF so if I replace q with (q+p) and r with (q+r) to get (p.(q+p))+(q+r), then will the latter be a Substitution Instance of the initial one?"

This example satisfies the condition: "... the same formula is substituted for the same variable each time it occurs."